# Inertial frame and its transformation in anti-de Sitter spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry, geodesics

From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space), I learned and was able to follow mathematically the definition of anti-de Sitter space. As the maximally symmetric solution to field equations with negative cosmological constant, the metric can be derived by considering the a $n+1$ dimensional spacetime with signature $(-,-,+,\cdots,+)$ together with the following constraint

$$-X_1^2-X_2^2+\sum_{i=3}^{n+1}X_i^2=-\alpha^2 .$$

One may introduce the parameterizaion $(\tau,\rho,\theta,\varphi_1,\cdots,\varphi_{n-3})$ as:
$$
\begin{cases}
X_1=\alpha\cosh\rho \cos \tau\\
X_2=\alpha\cosh \rho \sin \tau\\
X_i=\alpha \sinh \rho \,\hat{x}_i \qquad \sum_i \hat{x}_i^2=1
\end{cases}
$$
where $\hat{x}_i$ defines a $S^{n-2}$ sphere, namely, 
$$
\begin{cases}
\hat{x}_1=\sin \theta \sin \varphi _1 \dots \sin\varphi _{n-3}\\ 
\hat{x}_2=\sin \theta \sin \varphi _1 \dots \cos\varphi _{n-3}\\
\hat{x}_3=\sin \theta \sin \varphi _1 \dots \cos\varphi _{n-2}\\
\cdots
\end{cases}
$$ 
Therefore, the resultant line element of $\mathrm{AdS}_n$ metric
$$
ds^2 = \sum_{i=3}^{n+1} dX_i^2 - \sum_{j=1}^2 dX_j^2
$$
in terms of these coordinates reads
$$
d s^2=\alpha^2(-\cosh^2 \rho \, d \tau^2 + \, d \rho^2 + \sinh ^2 \rho \, d \Omega_{n-2}^2)
$$
where $\tau \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\rho \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

By further introducing the transformations $r\equiv\alpha\sinh \rho$ and $t\equiv\alpha\tau$, we arrive at the form of $\mathrm{AdS}_n$ metric usually found in literature:
$$
d s^2=-f(r) \, d t^2+\frac{1}{f(r)} \, d r^2+r^2 \, d \Omega_{n-2}^2 ,
$$
where $ f(r)=1+\frac{r^2}{\alpha^2} $.

It is straightforward to verify that the above metric is the solution of the following Einstein field equation

$$
R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} R + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = 0 \, , \qquad \Lambda < 0  \,. 
$$

derived by using variational principle from the Lagragian

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{16 \pi G}(R-2\Lambda) ,$$

with $\Lambda=\frac{-(n-1)(n-2)}{2\alpha^2} $.

Now, I have difficult to nevigate further to understand to following questions. What is the definition of an inertial observer in such a spacetime? Intuitively, an observer who sits at given spatial coordinates $r, \hat{x}_i$ (in particular, at the origin) is considered as inertial, (because I guess it should be easy to prove that his worldline is a geodesic, and every single worldline with constant spatial coordinates are essentially equivalent). Then consider two of such observers, how the proper-time difference between two events with given spatial coordinates for the first observer be measured by the second observer? In other words, is there any equivalent thing such as Lorentz transformation in this case?

A specific **question** as follows. Consider two such observers who try to measure the (same) wave signal emitted from a given source in the space. How do they compare their results? In flat space, this is related (mathematically) by Lorentz transformation, but in AdS case, what can I carry out the reasoning?

I am not very good at mathematics, is there any intuitive way to derive these things? Any reference or comment is welcome. Many thanks!

Comment: In flat spacetime, we can deduce a lot from symmetry, because it has a large symmetry (isometry) group, including Lorentz transformations and translations. In anti-de Sitter spacetime, we have a *different* large isometry group. However, using the embedding formalism that you started with, isometries of AdS can be related to Lorentz transformations in the ambient space, which can be used to infer some interesting things about geodesics in AdS. Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly Thanks for the comments. I was thinking about how two observers can compare their measurements. I have also updated the question.

Comment: Section 6.2 of the following textbook provides a brief discussion regarding geodesics, it might be helpful https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.3575.pdf